# Replacing parts of value (starts_with) in dataframe with values from a different dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, dplyr

I want to replace a part of the value in df1 with value from df2. If df1$col1 starts with the numbers in df2$col1, replace those four numbers (keep rest) with df2$col2. Same for df1$col2. Example: For 16122567 replace with 5059 resulting in 50592567. Have tried different kinds of starts_with, loops, for(i in ..),  mutate etc.. Anyone? (I'm new to R).

```
df1  col1        col2
1    16122567    89992567
2    17236945    16126548
3    95781657    19995670
4    16126972    56972541 

df2  col1    col2    
1    1612    5059    
2    1723    5044    
3    8999    5094    
4    1999    9053
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another approach using base R. We can create a function to do the check and manipulate the text and then apply that function to any column we want to modify.

```
# the data
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c(16122567, 17236945, 95781657, 16126972),
                  col2 = c(89992567, 16126548, 19995670, 56972541))

df2 <- data.frame(col1 = c(1612, 1723, 8999, 1999), 
                  col2 = c(5059, 5044, 5094, 9053))   

# a function to do the check and create the chimera strings
check_and_paste <- function(check1, check2, replacement) {
  res <- c()
  for (i in seq_along(check1)) {
    four_digits <- substr(check1[i], 1, 4)
    if (four_digits %in% check2) {
      res[i] <- paste(replacement[which(four_digits == check2)], 
                      substr(check1[i], 5, 8), 
                      sep = "")
    } else {
      res[i] <- check1[i]
    }
  }
  return(as.numeric(as.character(res))) # to return numbers
}

# apply to the first column
new_col1 <- check_and_paste(
  check1 = df1$col1,
  check2 = df2$col1,
  replacement = df2$col2
)

# and the second
new_col2 <- check_and_paste(
  check1 = df1$col2,
  check2 = df2$col1,
  replacement = df2$col2
)

# the new data frame
data.frame(new_col1, new_col2)
#  new_col1 new_col2
#1 50592567 50942567
#2 50446945 50596548
#3 95781657 90535670
#4 50596972 56972541
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way with `dplyr`. We can create a new column with first 4 characters of `col1`, `left_join` with `df2`, `replace` `NA`'s with four characters of `col2.x`. Finally, we use `substr` to replace values at specific position.

```
library(dplyr)

df3 <- df1 %>%
         mutate(col1 = substr(col1, 1, 4)) %>%
         left_join(df2 %>% mutate(col1 =  as.character(col1)), by = 'col1') %>%
         mutate(col2.y = ifelse(is.na(col2.y), substr(col2.x, 1, 4), col2.y), 
         col2.x = as.character(col2.x))

substr(df3$col2.x, 1, 4) <- df3$col2.y

df3
#  col1   col2.x col2.y
#1 1612 50592567   5059
#2 1723 50446548   5044
#3 9578 19995670   1999
#4 1612 50592541   5059
```

Comment: Thanks. I learned a lot, but had som difficulties with the substr only willing to take characters, not numbers.